# No module named 'testCases_v4'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I made a direct copy from the coursera`s code But it turns out like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pfyb.png)

What should I do?

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from testCases_v4 import *
from dnn_utils_v2 import sigmoid, sigmoid_backward, relu, relu_backward

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (5.0, 4.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

np.random.seed(1)
```

## that`s what I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5084fe490343> in <module>()
  2 import h5py
  3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from testCases_v4 import *
  5 from dnn_utils_v2 import sigmoid, sigmoid_backward, relu, relu_backward
  6 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testCases_v4'
```

Comment: Kindly share your code and explain about the issue you are facing to help you efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are importing a file that your system doesn't find (testCases_v4.py) that you probably don't have in your system. 
You can try to download the file from this link ([testCases_v4](http://git.syncsystems.org:64735/root/deeplearning_coursera/blob/90bf29cb59333607caf45f15be0aad7b3359a780/1_neural_networks_and_deep_learning/Week%204/Building%20your%20Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Step%20by%20Step/testCases_v4.py))
to your system in a place where python can find it.

You will probably get the same error for ddn_utils_v2.py and you can download it from [ddn_utils_v2](http://git.syncsystems.org:64735/root/deeplearning_coursera/blob/90bf29cb59333607caf45f15be0aad7b3359a780/1_neural_networks_and_deep_learning/Week%204/Building%20your%20Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Step%20by%20Step/dnn_utils_v2.py)

Comment: Hmm can't access the links, but it's an interesting resource to reach for one's own projects.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve realized the lib that I want to import is not in my localhost I need to 
import it from the jupyter notebook offered by coursera or download one from the web directly